# SandcastleのAPI Filterを包括的に指定したい

Tags: c#, sandcastle

Sandcastle Help File Builderを使用してC#ソリューションのヘルプを作成しています。

ヘルプに出力されるメンバーをアセンブリ(名前空間も分離しています)とアクセス修飾子に応じて変更したいのですが、GUIによるAPI Filterの指定はメンバー毎となっているため指定に非常に手間がかかります。リフレクションを使用してshfbprojファイルに除外メンバーを書き込む手もありますが、パターンマッチングやアドオンなどを使用してスマートに解決する方法はないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

プラグインによる`ApiFilter`のビルド時カスタマイズ方法を調べました。

1. プラグインを定義するプロジェクトで`Sandcastle Help File Builder`インストールフォルダ内のの`SandcastleBuilder.Utils.dll`を参照する。
2. `SandcastleBuilder.Utils.BuildComponent.IPlugIn`の実装クラスを作成し、`HelpFileBuilderPlugInExportAttribute`を指定する。
3. `IPlugIn.ExecutionPoints`で`new ExecutionPoint(BuildStep.GenerateApiFilter, ExecutionBehaviors.After)`を返す。
4. `IPlugIn.Initialize`で`BuildProcess`を確保し、`IPlugIn.Execute`で`BuildProcess.BuildApiFilter`に対して`MergeEntry`等で変更を加える。
5. 作成したアセンブリをSandcastleプロジェクトのルートディレクトリまたは`Project-specific components path`で指定したフォルダに配置する。
6. `Plug-Ins`で作成したプラグインを選択する。

なおMRefBuilder.configの`ApiFilter`はshfbprojと同様に`Namespace`、`Type`、`Member`の3層構造を取るのでエントリーの作成も階層化する必要があります。

```
[HelpFileBuilderPlugInExport("TestPlugIn")]
public class TestPlugIn : IPlugIn
{
    private BuildProcess _BuildProcess;
    private List<ExecutionPoint> _ExecutionPoints;

    public string ConfigurePlugIn(SandcastleBuilder.Utils.SandcastleProject project, string currentConfig)
    {
        return currentConfig;
    }

    public void Initialize(BuildProcess buildProcess, System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator configuration)
    {
        _BuildProcess = buildProcess;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ExecutionPoint> ExecutionPoints
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ExecutionPoints == null)
            {
                _ExecutionPoints = new List<ExecutionPoint>() 
                {
                    new ExecutionPoint(BuildStep.GenerateApiFilter, ExecutionBehaviors.After)
                };
            }
            return _ExecutionPoints;
        }
    }

    public void Execute(ExecutionContext context)
    {
        _BuildProcess.BuildApiFilter.MergeEntry(SandcastleBuilder.Utils.ApiEntryType.Namespace, "SandcastleTest.Sources.ShouldBeExcluded", false, true);

        if (_BuildProcess.BuildApiFilter.MergeEntry(SandcastleBuilder.Utils.ApiEntryType.Namespace, "SandcastleTest.Sources.MayBeExcluded", true, true))
        {
            var ns = _BuildProcess.BuildApiFilter.Last();

            ns.Children.MergeEntry(SandcastleBuilder.Utils.ApiEntryType.Class, "Class3", false, true);

            if (ns.Children.MergeEntry(SandcastleBuilder.Utils.ApiEntryType.Class, "Class4", true, true))
            {
                ns.Children.Last().Children.MergeEntry(SandcastleBuilder.Utils.ApiEntryType.Method, "Method", false, true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _BuildProcess = null;
        _ExecutionPoints = null;
    }
}
```